# Minimizing a function and plot it

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, variable

I have a long expression, depended on 3 different variables say "a", "b" and "p". Just as an example, a part of this expression is: z = p * Cos[x] * Sin[y]. I'm going to minimize this function for 0 <= x <=2pi and 0 <= y <=pi and then plot "z" versus "p". Any tip is highly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: If `p > 0`, then your problem is equivalent to `Minimize[{Cos[x] Sin[y], 0 <= x <= 2 \[Pi] && 0 <= y <= \[Pi]}, {x, 
  y}]`. Consider another case `p < 0` on your own.

Comment: I assume your example is a bit oversimplified because it can be solved by inspection. However, assume we have a function f of nx variables and a parameter p. We can minimize f over the variables by setting the derivatives to zero (strictly speaking, we should also check the 2.derivative to check if we not have a saddle point, but I leave this for the moment). This gives nx equations that can be solved for the variables as functions of p. Setting these into the original function, gives the searched for function of p.